# Sending TCP packet to the other device without connection

Tags: ethernet, tcp, networking

I think the sending packet to other device works like the following.
**1. The server device listens with port.**   `for example 80`
**2. The client connects to the server devices.**
    for example, the port of client that connects to server is 64000.
If the connection is established , the two devices could send tcp packets.
**And then could the 3rd device send the tcp packet to the client?**

Comment: Hi Andrew, and what is the question? is not clear what you want achive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

A TCP connection is established between 2 processes (usually running on 2 hosts), identified by the tuple IP address + TCP port. A 3rd host cannot join a TCP session.

To do so it would have to use the same tuple as one of the host, this mean faking to be some other host - i.e. hijacking the connection.

Comment: And how does p2p hole punching work? I thought that p2p hole punching worked the above.

Comment: Hole punching can work with stateless UDP where only the destination port is relevant but not with TCP.